# Difference between UIComponent and Sprite in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

What is the difference between a UIComponent and a Sprite in Flex.

Comment: Read the API docs at Adobe livedocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIComponent is a base class for all other visal components in Flex and it is a part of Flex framework. (Package  mx.core)

Sprite class is a basic display list building block and is part of Flash (Package flash.display)\

UIComponent is extends Sprite...

Check also:

[UIComponent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html) (check Inheritance UIComponent -> FLex Sprite -> Sprite -> ...)

[Sprite](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Sprite.html)

[HBox](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/HBox.html) (you can see that this visual component has UIComponent as it's base class
Inheritance Box -> Container -> UIComponent -> ...)